# Basic System Information in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am new, so I do apologize for anything that I may be dong wrong.

I am busy working on a personal project, (mainly for educational purposes). I need to obtain the basic system information of the system. For example, when you right click computer, and select properties, it gives you a break down on your system in Windows.

I am programming this in VB, and would like any suggestions or information to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class documentation.

Comment: Changed the language to the english version of the page.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had that covered.

Comment: you can probably get more info out of WMI - `System.Management`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186138%28v=vs.80%29.aspx you can also get some info from `System.Environment`